# Docker: what does runc:[2:INIT] mean?

Tags: docker, containers

Recently we have upgraded our Linux kernel of web server from 3.12.57-60.35 to 3.12.62-60.62.1.

After the upgrade, all docker containers can't be well started.

Each time when I try to start my container, a brand new `runc:[2:INIT]` process will be created and hang there, which takes 100% cpu load.

Meanwhile, the container failed to be started.

1. What does runc:[2:INIT] mean?
2. How to fix it?

[image]

### Some background information

```
> docker -v
Docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 78d1802

> uname -r
3.12.74-60.64.96-default

> containerd -v
containerd version 0.2.3

> docker-runc -v
runc version spec: 1.0.0-rc2-dev
```

### Docker info

```
docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 28
Server Version: 17.04.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: oci runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary:
containerd version:  (expected: 422e31ce907fd9c3833a38d7b8fdd023e5a76e73)
runc version: N/A (expected: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228)
init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.12.74-60.64.96-default
Operating System: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.19GiB
Name: pc23jamdevops01
ID: 5V4L:E4FT:6FYQ:JCNJ:GPKC:UZBW:O33D:PMKF:Y5X5:7T2X:GFG6
Docker Root Dir: /docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
  xxxxxxx(it's masked by me.)
Live Restore Enabled: false
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

### Trace

1. enabled the debug mode of docker
2. kill -SIGUSR1 $(pidof dockerd)

the trace shows

```
goroutine 795 [select, 29 minutes]:
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.(*Stream).waitOnHeader(0xc420774ff0, 0x10, 0xc4209caa80)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/transport.go:222 +0x101
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.(*Stream).RecvCompress(0xc420774ff0, 0x7f24a3df3ab0, 0xc4209cab40)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/transport.go:233 +0x2d
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*csAttempt).recvMsg(0xc421c98dd0, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, 0x0, 0x0)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/stream.go:515 +0x63b
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*clientStream).RecvMsg(0xc421954280, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, 0x0, 0x0)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/stream.go:395 +0x45
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.invoke(0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc421534090, 0x7f24a33f206d, 0x2a, 0x7f24a3c63380, 0xc42090e0e0, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, 0xc4209a0000, 0xc420978420, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/call.go:83 +0x185
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd.namespaceInterceptor.unary(0x7f24a339c737, 0x4, 0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0x7f24a33f206d, 0x2a, 0x7f24a3c63380, 0xc42090e0e0, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/grpc.go:35 +0xf6
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd.(namespaceInterceptor).(github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd.unary)-fm(0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0x7f24a33f206d, 0x2a, 0x7f24a3c63380, 0xc42090e0e0, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, 0xc4209a0000, 0x7f24a3df3b20, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/grpc.go:51 +0xf6
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*ClientConn).Invoke(0xc4209a0000, 0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0x7f24a33f206d, 0x2a, 0x7f24a3c63380, 0xc42090e0e0, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, 0x0, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/call.go:35 +0x10b
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.Invoke(0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0x7f24a33f206d, 0x2a, 0x7f24a3c63380, 0xc42090e0e0, 0x7f24a3c5e920, 0xc420b80840, 0xc4209a0000, 0x0, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/call.go:60 +0xc3
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/api/services/tasks/v1.(*tasksClient).Create(0xc420a5c5b0, 0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0xc42090e0e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420ec4a40, 0x1e)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/api/services/tasks/v1/tasks.pb.go:412 +0xd4
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd.(*container).NewTask(0xc42124f7e0, 0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0xc4223f5360, 0xc42000e9c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/containerd/containerd/container.go:250 +0x70a
github.com/docker/docker/libcontainerd.(*client).Start(0xc420a125b0, 0x7f24a3e29900, 0xc42003e028, 0xc4215fce40, 0x40, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc4210bd000, 0xc4207fd6f0, 0x0, ...)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/libcontainerd/client_daemon.go:289 +0x446
github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).containerStart(0xc420948000, 0xc421a458c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/start.go:185 +0x55f
github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).ContainerStart(0xc420948000, 0xc420731517, 0x40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f24a3a00640, 0xc421dd7601)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/start.go:95 +0x1c4
github.com/docker/docker/api/server/router/container.(*containerRouter).postContainersStart(0xc420ea83c0, 0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf290, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400, 0xc4211cf1d0, 0x7f24a339d6d5, 0x5)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/router/container/container_routes.go:203 +0x26a
github.com/docker/docker/api/server/router/container.(*containerRouter).(github.com/docker/docker/api/server/router/container.postContainersStart)-fm(0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf290, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400, 0xc4211cf1d0, 0x7f24a1ee64cc, 0x7f24a3c663a0)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/router/container/container.go:52 +0x6b
github.com/docker/docker/api/server/middleware.ExperimentalMiddleware.WrapHandler.func1(0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf290, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400, 0xc4211cf1d0, 0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf290)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/middleware/experimental.go:26 +0xda
github.com/docker/docker/api/server/middleware.VersionMiddleware.WrapHandler.func1(0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf230, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400, 0xc4211cf1d0, 0x18, 0xc421dd78f8)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/middleware/version.go:62 +0x401
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/authorization.(*Middleware).WrapHandler.func1(0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf230, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400, 0xc4211cf1d0, 0x7f24a1daefd7, 0x7f24a3571380)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/authorization/middleware.go:59 +0x7ab
github.com/docker/docker/api/server/middleware.DebugRequestMiddleware.func1(0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf230, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400, 0xc4211cf1d0, 0x7f24a3e29980, 0xc4211cf230)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/middleware/debug.go:25 +0x8db
github.com/docker/docker/api/server.(*Server).makeHTTPHandler.func1(0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/server.go:141 +0x19a
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc4214f36a0, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400)
  /usr/lib64/go/1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x46
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc421ceba40, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:103 +0x228
github.com/docker/docker/api/server.(*routerSwapper).ServeHTTP(0xc421a77360, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400)
  /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/docker-18.09.0_ce/components/engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/server/router_swapper.go:29 +0x72
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42020c4e0, 0x7f24a3e27d80, 0xc420854fc0, 0xc420690400)
  /usr/lib64/go/1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2697 +0xbe
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc420fe2320, 0x7f24a3e298c0, 0xc421196800)
  /usr/lib64/go/1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x653
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
  /usr/lib64/go/1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2798 +0x27d
```

Comment: That version of docker is rather old, out of support, and the runc version may have security vulnerabilities. I'd recommend upgrading to the latest 18.09 patch.

Comment: after upgrading docker version to 18.09, this issue still happens.

Comment: i still have it on 19 too.

Comment: I'd love to know what it is as well

Comment: we got same problem. nothing found as soultion

Comment: Still same problem here

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the server ? try maybe removing docker images and re-build it

Answer (score 7):

This is 2-years old at this point with no answers. It looks like the OP didn't follow up. As a point of interest for future readers though...

Although I don't know what was specifically causing the issue with docker, the question in the title does have a specific answer. In Linux the ps command will show the command and arguments that started the process. If it cannot do so it will show other useful information. In this case, it is showing the command, `runc`, followed by the run level of the process and the parent process:

```
command:[run-level:parent-process]
```

So, `init` is the parent and the process is at run-level `2`.

Comment: I cross-checked the referenced STEX Q but nowhere I can find that the init process happens to capitalize its name; the referenced Q makes it clear that ps simply prints the prctl-set information without tinkering with it.

Comment: why would the OP want to run a webserver on runlevel 2? Yes, there are use cases but how common is this?

Comment: finally, the referenced answer talks about "init [2]" special to init, but not ps, yet this question is about "runc:[2:INIT]".

Comment: ps does, yes, but you don't know whether the runc they're using has an init name that is already in capitals, and, they've used top, not ps. Although we can assume that it's a standard version of top, we don't really know that.

Comment: We don't know if the webserver runs in a container, only that containers are run on a machine the OP called a webserver. Therefore, we can't guess as to why these containers are running at lvl2. I doubt that its common at all tbh, but it is still a fact as far as I can tell from top.

Comment: Finally, yes, I appear to have put in the wrong link, and I can't find the right one now, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 5):

`runc init` is used to initialize the container runtime. The container startup flow is as follows:

docker client --> dockerd --> containerd --> containerd-shim --> runc

Your versions of `runc` and `containerd` are rather old so there could be several reasons why it could be stuck there. Try upgrading to runc version 1.0.1 and containerd version 1.4.9 to see if the error still persists. If it does, then I guess you could run `strace` on the `runc` processes to further debug it. One cause of a stuck runc process could be this deadlock bug: https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/pull/2871 which was fixed in runc v1.0.0-rc94

Answer (score 0):

Something rumored in the back of my mind when I stumbled upon this old Q related to runc, after just having answered [Libcontainer: What happens after the invocation of /proc/self/exe init](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76220640). And in fact, a quick search in `runc`'s code base and its dirty `nsenter` corner in particular then turned up this [code setting the name of the re-executed runc binary](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/d782db45364a1d4fa5a7b135963d09dcbbf83ac4/libcontainer/nsenter/nsexec.c#L1341):

```c
prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long)"runc:[2:INIT]", 0, 0, 0);
```

This fits much better into what the original Q describes; please note especially the all-CAPS "INIT". So these are in fact stuck runc processes, as pointed out here too by others.

I'm afraid that Software Engineer's A is a red herring though. The A about the output of the `ps` command he refers to nowhere mentions that either `ps` or the init process capitalizes process names (such as set via `prctl`). Why should it? In all my time, I've never seen an "INIT" process, and on top of this run-level 2 should have already rung all the bells of Christmas Eve, especially when operating web servers: run-level 2 is multi-user without networking, just look at [Wikipedia on Linux run-levels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Linux).